# Simple subtraction causes a broadcasting issue for different array shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I tried solving my issue using this [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), describing numpy broadcasting, but to no avail. How to subtract the following numpy arrays:

```
X = np.array([[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]],
              [[4,3,2,1],[4,3,2,1],[4,3,2,1]]])
X_mean = np.average(X_, axis=1)
```

When I do `X - X_mean` it states:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3,4) (2,4)
```

But doing `X[0] - X_mean[0]` gives the correct output:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep the dimensions aligned for [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to take place. You have -

```
In [4]: whos
Variable   Type       Data/Info
-------------------------------
X          ndarray    2x3x4: 24 elems, type `int64`, 192 bytes
X_mean     ndarray    2x4: 8 elems, type `float64`, 64 bytes
```

1. `Axis-0` of `X_mean` is already aligned with `axis-0` of `X`, so all good there.
2. `Axis-1` of `X_mean` is **to be** aligned with `axis-2` of `X`, so put in a new axis for `X_mean` there with [`None/np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) so that `axis-1` could be *pushed back* to `axis-2`.

Let's verify the shape-alignment -

```
In [7]: X_mean3D = X_mean[:,None,:]

In [8]: whos
Variable   Type       Data/Info
-------------------------------
X          ndarray    2x3x4: 24 elems, type `int64`, 192 bytes
X_mean     ndarray    2x4: 8 elems, type `float64`, 64 bytes
X_mean3D   ndarray    2x1x4: 8 elems, type `float64`, 64 bytes
```

Then, perform the subtraction that will bring in broadcasting -

```
In [5]: X - X_mean[:,None,:]
Out[5]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Comment: Alternatively, the `keepdims` argument of the `mean` method could be used: `result = X - X.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

As complement : According to [Numpy Broadcasting Rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) ,

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> - they are equal
> - one of them is 1

so the best idea is to shape data in a way the mean is made on axis 0.

In your case :

```
Y=np.rollaxis(X,1) # reshape (3,2,4)
```

`Y-Y.mean(0)` is now directly

```
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```